# Error: Call to a member function stores() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 Tables Users and Stores the relation between them is a Pivot table called user_store

```
User::find($user_id)->stores()
                ->sync(Store::whereIn('id', $store_ids)->get());
```

i know it's not very clear but if you have idea what is the cause of the problem

Comment: `find` can return `null` ... it didn't find a user by that id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that you are calling stores on user which happens to be `null`:

Depending on PHP version:

```
User::find($user_id)?->stores() ... // null safety

OR

$user = User::find($user_id);
if($user != null){
  $user->stores()...
}
```

Comment: Nice worked fine for me but I used another method i replaced find with findOrFail

Comment: It depends what you want to return as response; In case of ```findOrFail``` it will throw 404 not found if id is not found while with solution provided ```null``` will be returned.